# HTML borders for dynamic data

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a below data, I'm expecting to generate a border dynamically for each data set,

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Average Marks</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Marks Scored</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>Maths</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Student 1</td>
      <td>90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Maths</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Student 2</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Maths</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Student 3</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Student 1</td>
      <td>90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Student 2</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Actual table,

[image]

Expectation,

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreticiated

Comment: This isn't really a border issue, it's a `rowspan` issue.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function applyDynamicBorders() {
  const table = document.getElementById('data-table');
  const rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  let lastSubject = '';

  for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const currentSubject = rows[i].cells[0].textContent;
    if (currentSubject !== lastSubject) {
      // New group
      if (i > 1) {
        rows[i - 1].classList.add('group-end');
      }
      rows[i].classList.add('group-start');
    }
    if (i === rows.length - 1) {
      rows[i].classList.add('group-end');
    }
    lastSubject = currentSubject;
  }
}

window.onload = applyDynamicBorders;
```

```css
.group-start {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}

.group-end {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <table id="data-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Average Marks</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Marks Scored</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Maths</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>Student 1</td>
        <td>90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Maths</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>Student 2</td>
        <td>70</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Maths</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>Student 3</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>Student 1</td>
        <td>90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>Student 2</td>
        <td>70</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```